Jupyter Notebook is crashing when I want to run HuggingFace models
I am using Jupyter Notebook for running some ML models from HuggingFace.
I am using Mac (M2 Chip, Memory 32 GB)
This is my code:
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification, pipeline

# Step 1: Choose a pre-trained NER model from Hugging Face's Model Hub
# Here we use "dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english", which is a common NER model fine-tuned on the CoNLL-2003 dataset
model_name = "dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english"

# Step 2: Load the model and tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)

In step 2, my kernel always crashes. I have tried several models, but it is always the same. This is the error:
Kernel Restarting
The kernel for <kernel name> appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

Can you please help me?
My memory is not full, laptop is brand new.

You probably installed the intel version of some library, and it would crash when executing instructions not supported by your processor (like AVX512), make sure you install only ARM libraries. Some python libraries include native libraries too.
